# Why is Punctuator#punctuate in my Kafa Streams Processor invoked so many times

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a spring boot application which defines a topology as follows:

```
  @Autowired
  void buildTopology(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
    var builder = streamsBuilder.build();
    builder.addSource(TOPOLOGY_SOURCE, SOURCE_TOPIC);
    builder.addProcessor(TOPOLOGY_PROCESSOR, MyProcessor::new, TOPOLOGY_SOURCE);
    builder.addSink(TOPOLOGY_SINK, SINK_TOPIC, TOPOLOGY_PROCESSOR);
  }
```

and MyProcessor overrides init() and process as:

```
  @Override
  public void init(ProcessorContext<String, String> context) {
    context.schedule(
        Duration.ofSeconds(1),
        PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME,
        timestamp -> {
          log.info("Punctuate called - {}", Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp));
        });
  }

  @Override
  public void process(Record<String, String> record) {
    
  }
```

When i run the application, i get the following logs:

```
2023-01-05 11:54:43.541  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.539Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.542  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.542Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.542  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.542Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.542  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.542Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.542  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.542Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.542  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.542Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:43.543  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:43.543Z
2023-01-05 11:54:44.451  INFO 71096 --- [-StreamThread-1] : Punctuate called - 2023-01-05T16:54:44.451Z
```

Even though its scheduled for 1 second I see it being called 10-20 times per second but I expected it to be called once a second. Is this expected behavior / am I misunderstanding how WALL_CLOCK punctuation works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the source topic I was using for this test had 18 partitions, so the punctuator is being called once per partition.